# Eval command doesn't work at all, but it doesn't error

Tags: discord, discord.js, eval

I'm trying to make an eval command for my bot. It doesn't error, but it doesn't send a message to the console or the discord channel. Heres my eval code:

```js
const clean = async (client, text) => {
  if (text && text.constructor.name == "Promise")
    text = await text;
  if (typeof text !== "string")
    text = require("util").inspect(text, { depth: 1 });
  text = text
    .replace(/`/g, "`" + String.fromCharCode(8203))
      .replace(/@/g, "@" + String.fromCharCode(8203));
  text = text.replaceAll(client.token, "[REDACTED]");
  return text;
}

client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
  const args = message.content.split(" ").slice(1);

  if (message.content.startsWith(`${p}eval`)) {
    if (message.author.id !== 821682594830614578) {
      return;
    }
    
    try {
      const evaled = eval(args.join(" "));
      const cleaned = await clean(client, evaled);

      message.channel.send(`\`\`\`js\n${cleaned}\n\`\`\``);
    } catch (err) {
      message.channel.send(`\`ERROR\` \`\`\`xl\n${cleaned}\n\`\`\``);
    }

  }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you put a number as your ID... Discord.js IDs are in strings so you should put your ID into a string.

```js
    if (message.author.id !== "821682594830614578") {
      return;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have another one: if any way the token is revealed, how to censor it?

Comment: It seems that it already does that!

Comment: it only says the [redacted] in the `clean`, but when i would example say `!eval message.channel.send(process.env.token);` it would show the token.